# How to use a moving limited RANGE window to multiple ORDER BYs?

Tags: sql

This is my table:

| userID | Year | Month | Day | NbOfVisits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I would like to calculate the 7 days moving average, my query is as follows:

```
select userID,year,month,day, sum(nbofvisits) OVER (Partition by userID order by year,month,day RANGE BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as nbVisits7days
from table
order by userID, year, month, day;
```

But I keep getting this error: "A range window frame with value boundaries cannot be used in a window specification with multiple order by expressions". I understand I have multiple "Order Bys", but I can't think of a straight way other than this.

Comment: (year, month, day) can be converted to a single date value: `ORDER BY {expression to convert to a date}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Jon Armstrong's comment, I managed to run my intended query as follows:

```
select userID,year,month,day, sum(nbofvisits) OVER (Partition by userID order by TIMESTAMP(concat(annee,'-',mois,'-',jour)) RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as nbVisits7days
from table
order by userID, year, month, day;
```

Thank you!